# First Page empty when printing plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to create a pdf with several plots. More specifically, I want to save my plots, 4 in each page. Therefore, I have the following code in r (which works, but leaves a page empty -the first one-):

```
pdf("Plots/plots_numeric_four_in_page.pdf",paper="a4r",width = 14)

graphlist <- lapply(3:NCOL(agg_num), function(i) {
  force(i)
  tempColName=dataName_num[i]
  print (tempColName)
  p<-qplot(Group.1,agg_num[[tempColName]],data = agg_num,color=Group.2,geom = "line",main=tempColName) + xlab("Date") + ylab(paste("Count of ", tempColName)) +  geom_line(size=1.5)+ scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%Y"))+ 
    theme(legend.position="bottom",legend.direction="horizontal")+ guides(col=guide_legend(ncol=3))
})
do.call("marrangeGrob",c(graphlist,ncol=2,nrow=2))
dev.off()
```

It correctly displays around 50 plots, 4 in each page correctly in a PDF. However, it leaves the first page empty and starts from the second. I looked at marrangeGrob options, but I couldnt find anything to address the problem. Do you know any workaround, or any way to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There's a known bug between ggplot2 in `gridExtra` that's causing this for some `marrangeGrob`'s that contain ggplots. Manually overriding the `grid.draw.arrangelist` function ([src](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/blob/master/R/arrangeGrob.r#L252)) (`marrangeGrob` returns an `arrangelist` object) may potentially fix it (suggested [here](https://github.com/baptiste/gridextra/issues/33)).

```
grid.draw.arrangelist <- function(x, ...) {
  for(ii in seq_along(x)){
    if(ii>1) grid.newpage()  # skips grid.newpage() call the first time around
      grid.draw(x[[ii]])
  }
}
```

It may be safer to define a new class for the `arrangelist` object in question and apply the fix to it than override `grid.draw` for every `marrageGrob` call in scope.