# R is saving empty sheets for several plots generated using a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, plot

I have an issue when I'm trying to save several plots in a pdf file using R.
I created these plots using the [`RTCGA` package](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/RTCGA.html). The command to generate one plot is the next:

```
kmTCGA(my_data, ##My data is stored in a list
   explanatory.names = "SOCS1", 
   pval = T, 
   conf.int = F,  
   risk.table = F)
```

To save multiple plots I'm using the next code:

```
pdf("../mypath/KMplots.pdf", height = 8, width = 10)
for(i in names(categories)){ ##names of my datasets
  for(j in variables){ ##Names of the genes I'm analyzing
    print(kmTCGA(categories[[i]], 
           explanatory.names = j, 
           pval = T, 
           conf.int = F, 
           risk.table = F))
  }
}
dev.off()
```

However, when I inspect the pdf file, the first page is empty or in blank. Does anyone know how to save my data without this empty page?

Thanks in advance!

Rodo

Comment: You should search for "[r] pdf empty page". I'm reasonably sure this has been asked and answered more than once. My memory is that the solution used the `onefile` parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. After searching, I found that `onefile` works in cases in which you are not using for loops to generate the plots. It looks like there is a bug in `ggplot` and `gridExtra` which causes [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40495336/11456351).